# Drawing from a class libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi I'm currently trying to make a picross game with libdgx and I'm having trouble drawing images to the screen from within a class. Just wondering what parameters I have to pass a draw/render function within the class, the code I have so far is below. I'm fairly new to programming with libdgx so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
package PicrossGameObjects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Tile { 

    Texture BlankTile;
    Texture RedTile;
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;

public Tile(int x, int y){
    BlankTile = new Texture("BlankTile.png");
    RedTile = new Texture("RedTile.png");
    xCoord = x;
    yCoord = y;
}

public void Render(SpriteBatch batch){      

}
    }
```

Comment: This is not a specific answer, however I suggest you start watching some of these video tutorials on libgdx: 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L

You will find your answer when you watch the videos related to the topic. Take notice to the Box2d videos, I am assuming that is what you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
boolean isBlank = true;

public void render(SpriteBatch batch){

    if(isBlank)
    batch.draw(BlankTile,xCoord,yCoord);
    else
    batch.draw(RedTile,xCoord,yCoord);

}
```

Notice that you need a boolean variable to decide what kind of tile you want to draw. Also loading a new texture for every tile should have a really bad effect for performance. You should read about using TextureAtlas, AssetManager. Or just pass your Texture as a parameter to your Tile instead of creating new one every time.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not very good at understanding how everything should be structured at the moment. Just to be clear if I used a texture atlas would that be in the tile class or where I create the Tile?

Comment: It wouldn't be in tile class. It could be in a class that creates the tiles or even better: in a separate class where you hold all your resources.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help and I'm finally making some progress  with the game!